# The parameterized query '(@id nvarchar(4000),@name nvarchar(4000),@project nvarchar(4000)' expects the parameter '@id', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server

while storing data into database through wcf I am getting  error. I am taking input from android client through textboxes.
**ERROR:** The parameterized query '(@ID nvarchar(4000),@Name nvarchar(4000),@Project nvarchar(4000)' expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

The c# code for data insertion is

```
 [DataContract]
    public class studentinfo
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Project")]
        public string Project { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Result")]
        public string Result { get; set; }


    }

  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "SaveData")]
        void SaveData(studentinfo studentinfo);



 public void SaveData(studentinfo studentinfo)
    {
        SqlConnection con;


        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myproject.Properties.Settings.MyConnection"].ConnectionString);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }



    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Result (ID,Name,Project,Result) values(@ID,@Name,@Project,@Result)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", studentinfo.ID);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", studentinfo.Name);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project", studentinfo.Project);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", studentinfo.Result);


    int Valid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



    con.Close();

}
```

**Edited:** here is android client side code:

```
public class MarksActivity extends Activity {

     private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc";
    Button btnsave, btncal;
    EditText txtid, txtname, txtproject, txtviva, txtpres, txtconfi, txtsystem, txttotal;
    double h=0;
    double s=0;
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double z=0;
    String text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.marks);

        btnsave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);

        text    = "";

        btncal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncal);


        txtid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtid);
        txtname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        txtproject=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtproject);
        txttotal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txttotal);

        txtviva=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtviva);
        txtpres=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpres);
        txtconfi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtconfi);
        txtsystem=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsystem);

        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveData();
                }
            });


}



    public void saveData() {




        try{

            boolean isValid = true;


                h=Double.parseDouble(txtviva.getText().toString());
                s=Double.parseDouble(txtpres.getText().toString());
                x=Double.parseDouble(txtconfi.getText().toString());
                y=Double.parseDouble(txtsystem.getText().toString());
                  z= h+s+x+y;
                  txttotal.setText(Double.toString(z));




                  if (isValid) {

                        // POST request to <service>/SaveVehicle


                    //Connect to the server
                    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI +"/SaveData");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                        // Build JSON string
                        JSONStringer getdata = new JSONStringer()
                            .object()
                                .key("studentinfo")
                                    .object()
                                        .key("ID").value(txtid.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Name").value(txtname.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Project").value(txtproject.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Result").value(txttotal.getText().toString())
                                    .endObject()
                                .endObject();
                        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getdata.toString());

                        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

                        // Send request to WCF service
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

                        // Reload plate numbers

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }

    }
```

I did try some methods provided in other answers but unable to solve this problem. 
Please help me to solve it

Comment: Did you checked in debugger that id isn't null?

Comment: Is that the *exact* error message?  Because it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @RBarry Young yes it is the exact error message.

Comment: @RBarry Young you mean why not first letter is caps so here it is the exact one edited above as well: The parameterized query '(@ID nvarchar(4000),@Name nvarchar(4000),@Project nvarchar(4000)' expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `studentinfo.ID` value is `null`? If you want to pass null as a parameter you need to use `DBNull` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)

Jason

Comment: how to know that studentinfo.ID value is null? I am sorry for asking stupid question I just start learning programming.

Comment: I am not getting how to use DBNull to check for Null value

Comment: if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(studentinfo.ID)) { ... }

Comment: @Chris Lively I tried like that  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(studentinfo.ID))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("string is empty");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("data entered successfully");
            }  its shopwing string is empty and afterwards giving same error. why its generating this error although I am giving value for ID?

Comment: Where do you set the value for ID?

Comment: I am sending values from android client, should I paste my android client code as well?

Comment: If the message is showing that the string is empty, then it's empty.  Meaning that either you are not collecting it or it isn't being passed.  Check all that.

Comment: @Chris Lively it means there is some problem in client side code? because I am taking input from android client and then pass it to sql database through json wcf.

Comment: @user2684131: It's likely in the client code.  You need to trace through the entire conversation to figure out what's going on.  I suspect ID isn't the only value that is null; my guess is that all of them are.

Comment: @Chris Lively, yes you are right when I checked through fiddler c# wcf service commit to database and store empty row. It means the wcf required to read data properly but I 'm unable to figure out how? Please have a look at wcf  code and point me where it is wrong and how to make it read data.